# Partial specialization with reference template parameter fails to compile in VS2005

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2005, compiler-errors, partial-specialization

I have code that boils down to the following:

```
template <typename T> struct Foo {};
template <typename T, const Foo<T>& I> struct FooBar {};

////////

template <typename T> struct Baz {};

template <typename T, const Foo<T>& I>
struct Baz< FooBar<T,I> >
{
 static void func(FooBar<T,I>& value);
};

////////

struct MyStruct
{
 static const Foo<float> s_floatFoo;
};

// Elsewhere: const Foo<float> MyStruct::s_floatFoo;

void callBaz()
{
 typedef FooBar<float, MyStruct::s_floatFoo> FloatFooBar;
 FloatFooBar myFloatFooBar;
 Baz<FloatFooBar>::func(myFloatFooBar);
}
```

This compiles successfully under GCC, however, under VS2005, I get:

```
error C2039: 'func' : is not a member of 'Baz<T>'
        with
        [
            T=FloatFooBar
        ]
error C3861: 'func': identifier not found
```

However, if I change `const Foo<T>& I` to `const Foo<T>* I` (passing `I` by pointer rather than by reference), and defining `FloatFooBar` as:

```
typedef FooBar<float, &MyStruct::s_floatFoo> FloatFooBar;
```

Both GCC and VS2005 are happy.

What's going on? Is this some kind of subtle template substitution failure that VS2005 is handling differently to GCC, or a compiler bug?

(The strangest thing: I *thought* I had the above code working in VS2005 earlier this morning. But that was before my morning coffee. I'm now not entirely certain I wasn't under some sort of caffeine-craving-induced delirium...)

Comment: The code seems to be OK. Looks like a bug in VS2005.

Comment: The code compiles with Comeau online, so is probably OK, limit to VS2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it looks like VS2005 uses the first template specification of `Baz`

```
template <typename T> struct Baz {};
```

This struct does indeed not contain a member named `func`. Looks like VS2005 doesn't deduce the template parameters correctly.

Comment: Yeah, it's looking more and more like a bug in VS.